# Contact custom MimeType is not shown on Android versions less than 7

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contact-mimetype

I am trying to modify my existing contacts on my device.

I have implemented all the related stuff (AuthenticationService, AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter, SyncService, AbstractAccountAuthenticator etc..) following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) guides/examples  and [this](https://github.com/nemezis/SampleContacts).

All works fine on my Samsung Galaxy S7 that has Android 7: now my contacts have a new custom function, if I select it, an Activity of my Application is launched. This is accomplished creating a contacts.xml file and using a custom MIMETYPE (as explained in the links above).

Unfortunately this approach seems to not work on devices running Android with version < 7. My custom function is not shown although everything seems to work correctly and no error is detected.

If someone knew something concerning it, it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to be more specific, on pre-7 android are you able to add your `mimetype` to a `RawContact`? If so, are you seeing the custom row in the `Contacts` app? If so, what happens when you click it?

Comment: Yes, I see a custom row inside each contact of my Contacts app. When I select my custom row, an activity of my Application is launched. In Android 5 I can't see my custom row.

Comment: in Android 5, if you query for that raw-contact's data from ContactsContract.Data table, do you see a line with your mimetype?

Comment: Yes I do. In fact on Android 7 it works, I'm confused...

Comment: can you paste the exact data in that line containing your mimetype? if it's formatted properly it should at least appear in the contact's profile

Comment: I think it is formatted properly, it works on the Samsung Galaxy S7. Maybe the problem is inside the contacts.xml. Now I'm using: detailColumn = DATA3  and summaryColumn = DATA2. I've tried also other comobinations (DATA1, DATA2 etc..) but it doesn't work.

Comment: please paste the full contacts.xml file and the whole data line you're to your contacts

Comment: contacts.xml:                                                           
                                                                                <ContactsAccountType xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ContactsDataKind

        android:detailColumn="data3"
        android:detailSocialSummary="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/sea_16"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.provacontatti.Main2Activity"
        android:summaryColumn="data2" />

</ContactsAccountType>

Comment: Add my custom mimetype to a new row contact:                                                                                                                           op = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIME)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Hello")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2,"hello");
        ops.add(op.build());

Comment: Moreover there could be a difference between ContactSource and ContactsAccountType... The documentation is so poor.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm assuming the ";" in your contacts.xml is a typo, or your project wouldn't compile
2. Try removing the `android:detailSocialSummary` line from your contacts.xml as most examples I know don't have that
3. Instead of `ContactsAccountType` try `ContactsSource`, see [this](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/res/xml/contacts.xml) as reference.
4. The mimetype usually doesn't point to an activity within your app, it should be: `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.<your package>.<some action>` but I don't think that's the problem you're having

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried all the steps above... but thanks for that link! I think it will be very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Check Mime Type line, you must have to add .profile at the end and /vnd..profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContactsSource
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ContactsDataKind
    android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.krishna.test.profile"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:summaryColumn="data2"
    android:detailColumn="data3" />
</ContactsSource>
```